# Words to start how a mentioned task is performed

Tags: word-request

Consider this pattern

> It is possible to do X, .....(To do so/For this purpose/To do this/To achieve it.. ?) the user must....

What are proper words for this purpose?

Comment: The phrases *to do so* and *to do this* are fine provided that they follow the sentence in which you say *It is possible to do X*.

Comment: Right. The others are not so good. We say someone "achieves" an _objective_, but not a _process_. "For this purpose" seems to say that X is a _purpose_ (a reason), not a _process_.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock : The objective can easily be "to do X", not X.  I think we simply need more context.

Comment: It would be helpful if you write a full sentence (without variables).

Answer (score 1):

There could be dozens of opinions. You must clear the question.

Anyway, if I take a simple example, we can go like this -

> It is possible to climb Mt. Everest. (But^) For that, you must be physically fit.

^*True, we require more context in this to have a precise answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we can say "**It is done by**", "**It is basically done by**" in a passive form.